# HDFS file permission issue

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I have created a directory `/tmp/ran-test` with access permission(400) in HDFS.
I tried to copy a file to the directory and got permission denied error.
But, my colleague could able to copy files to the directory without any error.
I am wondering now how it works.

I would appreciate if somebody give their explanation.

Thanks,
Jee

Comment: Was your colleague running as root or using sudo, perhaps?

Comment: your colleague could be root :).

Comment: or he could give write permissions if this was allowed to him, put files to over there, and revoke the write permissions again

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My colleague is not a root. But, i heard that he was given admin permission due to some other permission issues. We are using active directory. So, How to check if he is in the root group.

Comment: Hi dmi,  this is the directory in hdfs.                                                     dr--------+  - jkris03    hdfs          0 2017-03-20 15:36 /tmp/ranger_test

Comment: Hi Andrew, My colleague did not run as root user.

Answer (score 1):

The directory in question has HDFS ACL permissions set. Notice the `+` character in the permission string of `hdfs dfs -ls` output.

```
dr--------+ - jkris03 hdfs 0 2017-03-20 15:36 /tmp/ranger_test
```

This `+` determines the directory has an ACL (Access Control Lists) and this is providing the user with additional permission to write to it.

To view the ACL permissions set for this directory,

```
hdfs dfs -getfacl /tmp/ranger_test
```